# What does " pulp" mean in this context?

Tags: context, meaning, what

the pulp for the marriage made by the empress dowager has made me a fool to the whole world

Comment: News copy, perhaps? More context needed.

Comment: What's the source for the sentence?

Comment: It's from the book. A girl is pregnant by the emperor. His mother the empress is arranging their wedding. This line of the guy, who is against the wedding and doubts that she's pregnant. Anyway, I searched some dictionaries. Could it be "nonsense", "cheesy drama"?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Please could you add a little more information, in particular whether you're reading a translation and which original lanuage is involved ("empress dowager" suggests a few, but I don't want to keep guessing without some guidance :)).

Comment: 'It's from the book' isn't much help.

Comment: It's no help at all, really!

Comment: [**pulp**](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/pulp.html) - *Popular or sensational writing that is regarded as being of poor quality.* I seriously doubt the cited text was originally written in English (even the collocation "a fool to the whole world" seems more common as a translation from Japanese than a natural Anglophonic usage). So I think this is just a matter of slightly "unusual" choices in translation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It would make sense if it said *the pulp **of** the marriage*, which would mean, in this context, *the ruin of the marriage.* If that was the intended meaning, then it was simply the wrong preposition that was used in the translation.

Comment: You may be right about the preposition, but even so "pulp" isn't the right English translation. Sezim, what is the name of the book, please?

Comment: Treating me as passive pulp, by alleging that I am the father without checking the facts, makes me a fool.

Comment: "A girl is pregnant by the emperor. His mother the empress", huh? How about being categorical: No, it cannot be pulp or cheesy drama or anything else like that. Given the very poor English, it must be something about what the empress dowager said or did...,.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a bad translation.

There is a similar English word, *pap*, which is sometimes used to mean boring, unappetising food.

It is clear from context that the intended meaning is something like,

> The empress dowager, who was supposedly arranging some or all of the catering for a wedding banquet, failed to provide a sufficient quality of food, and the result is a great deal of shame.

If the source material was originally (say) Chinese, there are several words that could be literally translated "pulp" that actually (also, and usually) refer to meat or fruit (as in "flesh"), such as 肉.

You will need to provide a little more information about the source to narrow down the source of the confusion (and the intended meaning).

Other possibilities, though they seems less likely to me, are:

- the sense of "soap opera" or "poor quality writing" that has been brought up in the comments; if so a better translation would be something like "melodrama" or "chaos".
- at a stretch, one might think of the English phrase *make a **hash** of*, which would fit the sense of *ruin*, and the general feeling of the sentence; again, knowing the source would perhaps help settle it.

Comment: If that's the intended meaning, then *pulp* could still be correct word, if using *pulp* to mean ruined. The problem would be the preposition—it should read *the pulp **of** the marriage*.

Comment: It's really not the right word to use, in English, in such a context, *even if* that's the intended meaning. If the meaning were, as you suggested in your comment on the question, "ruin", it's still not remotely idiomatic, and it doesn't make a whole lot of sense (it's clear she did something embarrassing, but having a bit more of the surrounding dialogue / narrative would help).

Comment: +1 for saying it is bad translation. "It sure is", said the translator mechanically. :)

Comment: @WillCrawford It's metaphorical. I see nothing wrong with it—assuming, as I said, it's corrected to *pulp* ***of***. I know I've heard it used that way before. So, it's idiomatic as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @Lambie brilliant, thank you :)

Comment: And no, Jason, it's still terrible. If you want to insist on pulp, AT A PINCH, you could say ***made of** the marriage*. Or ***The train wreck of a marriage** arranged by...*.

Comment: It would have to be: The pulp the empress made of the marriage has made a fool out of me. And that still sounds absolutely 'orrible.